# Размер выборки данных из таблицы в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица data, в которой есть записи, для которых поле name принимает значения "R1", "R2" или "R3".

Как можно посчитать размер в МБ только тех данных, у которых поле name = "R1". Без создания дополнительных таблиц.

Comment: *Как можно посчитать размер в МБ только тех данных* Ну скажем так - весьма приблизительно. Берёте размер всей таблицы (`pg_relation_size`), количество записей - всего и только с нужным атрибутом, и по пропорции считаете. Конечно, плюс-минус лапоть, но лучше, чем ничего.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(pg_column_size(tablename)) 
  from tablename 
  where "name" = 'R1';
```

Будет объём в байтах.

Способ по-прежнему не точный: отдельная табличка будет отличаться по объёму, т.к. не считаются заголовки страниц данных, фрагментация, `fillfactor`. Но представление об объёме данных даст вполне внятное.

Comment: По-моему, `R1` - это значение поля, а не имя поля...

Comment: @Akina, мне тоже так показалось. Иии?

Comment: ... и. как я понимаю, фигвам. *pg_column_size shows the space used to store any individual data value*, а вовсе даже не объём записей с этим значением.

Comment: pg_column_size можно применять к таплу. Это тоже тип данных.